# If reputation reaches daily maximum

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

What happens if a person answers a question when he has a daily reputation of say 187 on a particular day, and then someone accepts his answer and as well as gives an upvote ? I had read somewhere that the max daily reputation is 200. What happens in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They (as gender-neutral term) earn 25 rep, not 13. [Help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) says:

> Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not subject to the daily reputation limit.